# Enabling proxy protocol in Nginx for just one vhost without breaking the others?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I just set up HAProxy on a server by itself to act as a reverse proxy. This will send the traffic to a main server that's running Nginx.

I got it *almost* working, aside from being able to pass the original IP through from the proxy server to the web server.

I'm using `mode tcp` in haproxy since a lot of the traffic coming in will already be on port 443 using SSL. I read that I can't use the `option forwardfor` in tcp mode, and I can't send SSL traffic using `mode http`. So I added `send-proxy` to the server lines, and then tried to enable the proxy protocol on Nginx.

That actually worked for the domain I'm running, but we have about 10 other virtualhost domains being hosted on that same machine, and as soon as I enabled proxy protocol on one vhost separately, it broke ALL of our other domains pointing to that server, as they all started timing out.

Is there a way around this? Can I enable proxy protocol for just one virtualhost on Nginx without breaking the rest of them? Or is there a way to just use http mode with the forwardfor option, even if it's sending SSL traffic?

Below is my haproxy config, with the IPs redacted:

```
global
    maxconn 10000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
defaults
    retries 3
    timeout client 30s
    timeout server 30s
    timeout connect 30s
    mode tcp
frontend incoming
    bind *:80
    bind *:443
    option tcplog
    default_backend client_proxy
backend client_proxy
    use-server ps_proxy_http if { dst_port 80 }
    use-server ps_proxy_https if { dst_port 443 }
    server ps_proxy_http XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80 send-proxy
    server ps_proxy_https XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 send-proxy
```

This is my first time using HAProxy as a reverse proxy, so any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: please can you share also the nginx config

Comment: how about you move/copy that vhost with proxy protocol to another port? is taht acceptable workaround?